# Groking/Parsing portions of a Number in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am attempting to parse a portion a date from a string and the numbers are clumped together like this:

file-20170707.log

I would like to turn this into file-[yyyy.MM.dd] -- standard elastic format.

I have tried a few things so far and played with the grok constructors so far.

%{[0-9]{4}:year}%{[0-9]{2}:month}%{[0-9]{2}:day} -- variations on this pattern with no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Grok should set values for `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY` for you from the line you've shown as an example:

```
file-(?<YEAR>[0-9]{4})(?<MONTH>[0-9]{2})(?<DAY>[0-9]{2})\.log
```